# Converting Nema 6-30R to Nema 6-15R

Tags: wiring

Can I convert a 6-30R recepticle to a 6-15R if I change the breaker in the box to a 15A breaker as well?

Comment: Will need to check if the 6-15 can fit the 10 gauge wire under the screws.  If not you can pigtail 12 gauge to the 10 gauge to fit.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. That is the safe direction to make the change.

Or you could use a 6-20R and a 20A breaker, since as with 5-20Rs, the 6-20R receptacle will take a 6-15P or a 6-20P plug, and that's an acceptable situation per code specifically for 20A and 15A devices.